# CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived event is only executed once

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using push notification with FCM in a Xamarin Forms application, so everything looks to be working fine except for one specific case.

Used package: **`Plugin.FirebasePushNotification`**

The event `CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived +=` is being called only once when the application is open and when the app starts.

if I send 2 or more notifications from the server it's only called for the first notification, after that stop working. However the notification popup is always shown no matter what, even when the is in foreground, background, killed.

I want this to be called when the app is open because I need to perform an action depending on the notification data.

I'm testing in **iOS 15.3.1**

Intructions: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md

Versions:

`"Plugin.FirebasePushNotification" Version="3.4.1"`
`"Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2337"`

Thanks in advance.

My entire `AppDelegate.cs` Code:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        NSObject _onKeyboardShowObserver;
        NSObject _onKeyboardHideObserver;
       
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();

            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            RegisterKeyBoardObserver();
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

        }

        // To receive notifications in foreground on iOS 9 and below.
        // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
        //[Export("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification")]
        [Export("messaging:didReceiveRemoteNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
            // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

            // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method. 
            // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
            // automatically with method swizzling enabled.
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Do your magic to handle the notification data
            System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
            
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);            
        }

        void RegisterKeyBoardObserver()
        {
            if (_onKeyboardShowObserver == null)
                _onKeyboardShowObserver = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow((object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args) =>
                {
                    NSValue result = (NSValue)args.Notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString(UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey));
                    CGSize keyboardSize = result.RectangleFValue.Size;
                    MessagingCenter.Send<object, KeyboardAppearEventArgs>(this, Constants.iOSKeyboardAppears, new KeyboardAppearEventArgs { KeyboardSize = (float)keyboardSize.Height });
                });
            if (_onKeyboardHideObserver == null)
                _onKeyboardHideObserver = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide((object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args) =>
                    MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, Constants.iOSKeyboardDisappears, Constants.iOSKeyboardDisappears));
        }
        
        public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication application)
        {
            if (_onKeyboardShowObserver == null)
            {
                _onKeyboardShowObserver.Dispose();
                _onKeyboardShowObserver = null;
            }

            if (_onKeyboardHideObserver == null)
            {
                _onKeyboardHideObserver.Dispose();
                _onKeyboardHideObserver = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you subscribe to the event (where is CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += part). It should be inside `protected override void OnStart ` in your App.cs

Comment: Yes, it is inside the `protected override void OnStart` method. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions for troubleshooting .

1. As `Almis` mentioned , place the code into `OnStart` of App.cs.
2. Make sure that initialization is correct, check [iOS Initialization](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#ios-initialization) .

If problem persists , consider raising issue on github .

Comment: Checking on the iOS initialization I found out that the Type for the FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled property was set as string and it should be boolean and tested again but no success.\\

Here the logs I the notifications are received: `WillPresentNotification: Notification request not found`
`UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.`

Comment: Also, regarding to your 3rd  point: if the `OnNotificationReceived` is supposed to trigger after we click on the notification, why it's being triggered on the first notification arrival?  they also have an event called `OnNotificationOpened`.
 
@ColeX **Thanks for the answers and suggestions**

Comment: @FranklinFrias You're right OnNotificationReceived should be triggered every time you receive a notification. There are some people that complain about version 13.5.xx, maybe try to test it on an older version to see if that is the issue.

Comment: @FranklinFrias you're right , `OnNotificationReceived` should be triggered when receiving the notification . If possible could you provide the entire code in AppDelegate.cs ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT After different tests I could find what is causing the issue, but I don’t know why. One of the things I do in the `OnNotificationReceived` event is show a local Push Notification by calling the `NotificationCenter.Current.Show` method, and that is what is causing the problem. When I comment the line of code that calls `await NotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification)` start working fine.

Comment: Once the `NotificationCenter.Current.Show` is executed, then the `CrossFirebasePushNotification` plugging starts working like if my App is in background or foreground. that's crazy

Comment: It's weird, however if problem has been solved , could you please post the solution/workaround and mark it as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

After different tests I could find what is causing the issue, but I don’t know why.
One of the things I do in the `OnNotificationReceived` event is show a local Push Notification by calling the `NotificationCenter.Current.Show` method, and that is what is causing the problem. When I comment the line of code that calls await `NotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification)` start working fine.

Once the `NotificationCenter.Current.Show` is executed, then the CrossFirebasePushNotification plugging starts working like if my App is in background or foreground.